# Biblioteca de paginação para .Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-web-api

Já trabalhei em alguns frameworks como Spring e NestJS, e lá eu trabalhava com uma biblioteca que listava uma query pagina.

Aqui no .Net Core, tenho que criar um método para trabalhar com isso. Por exemplo:

```
public PagedSearchDTO<PersonVO> FindWithPagedSearch(string name, string sortDirection, int pageSize, int page)
        {

            page = page > 0 ? page - 1 : 0;
            string query = @"select * from persons p where 1 = 1 ";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) query = query + $"and p.firstname like '%{name}%' ";

            query = query + $" order by p.firstname {sortDirection} limit {pageSize} offset {page}";

            string countQuery = @"select count(*) from persons p where 1 = 1 ";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) countQuery = countQuery + $" and p.name like '%{name}%' ";

            var persons = _repository.FindWithPagedSearch(query);

            int totalResults = _repository.GetCount(countQuery);

            return new PagedSearchDTO<PersonVO>
            {
                CurrentPage = page + 1,
                List = _converter.ParseList(persons),
                PageSize = pageSize,
                SortDirections = sortDirection,
                TotalResults = totalResults
            };
        }
```

Gostaria de sever, se já existe uma biblioteca, de preferência oficial da linguagem, que trabalhe com essa lógica de paginação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Não existe** nenhuma biblioteca oficial que faça paginação.

Existem pacotes Nuget que fazem isso como o [`AspNetCore.Mvc.Paging`](https://github.com/cloudfy/aspnetcore-paging)
Você pode pesquisar por outros pacotes no site https://www.nuget.org/

Na documentação oficial existe um [tutorial sobre paginação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.0#adicionar-a-funcionalidade-de-pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-%C3%A0-p%C3%A1gina-%C3%ADndice-de-alunosadd-paging-functionality-to-the-students-index-page) caso queira fazer você mesmo.

Comment: A documentação que colocou está ótima, mas seria ainda melhor se colocasse um exemplo prático na resposta. :)

Comment: George eu não coloquei na resposta o exemplo porque o tutorial sobre paginação tem o exemplo completo. Seria apenas repetir o que já esta lá.